# why does snprintf copy different values eventhough same variables are copied to string array each time

Tags: c, string, pointers

My problem is summarized in the below simple code. I expect in both the printfs copy the same value to this string each time. But I see for one statement ascii value is copied , and for the other actual value is copied.Why is this difference ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[20];
   int id = 1;
   memset(string,0,20);
   snprintf((char *) (string),19,"%d",id);
   snprintf((char *) (string+10),19,"%d",id);
   return 0;
}
```

output (using gdb)

```
(gdb) p  string
$1 = "1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\61\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
(gdb)
```

Comment: I'd say debugger printing heursitics...

Comment: @EricPostpischil . Edited. I changed locally for readability.

Comment: Aside: You would not want to use `snprintf((char *) (string+10),19,"%d",id);` in real code, as the `19` is too large for the available memory starting at `string+10`. Use `sizeof string - 10`. And `19` is not necessary for the first one; `snprintf` limits itself to one less than the given quantity, so `20` would be okay, and `sizeof string` would be better.

Comment: `string + 20` is already a `char *`, don't cast it with `(char *)` and allow the compiler to check the result for you, so you don't get an undetected error, resulting of no complain due to making an explicit type conversion.  Don't abuse casts, as they are dangerous if abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the results produced by the two `snprintf` calls. In both cases, the character “1” is written to the given location, followed by a null character.

There is a difference in how gdb displays the data. For bytes 0 and 1 of `string`, it shows:

```
1\0
```

which means the character “1” followed by the character with code 0, also called the null character. For bytes 10 and 11 of `string`, it shows:

```
\61\0
```

which means the character with octal code 61 followed by the character with code 0. The ASCII code for “1” is 61 in octal (49 in decimal), so this is the same value as in byte 0, presuming of course that your C implementation uses ASCII.

The only difference is in the display. This display is a consequence of gdb behavior and not your program. We may speculate that gdb displayed the “1” in byte 10 in octal instead of as a literal “1” because it is preceded or surrounded by non-printable characters or because it is after the null character that ends the normal string.

Comment: If it had printed it as ..`\0\01\0\0`.. it would have been easy to mistake for a single `\1` character....

Answer (score 1):

The character '1' and the octal value '\61' are *presentations* of the *same* value.

Consider:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at main.c:11                                                           
11         return 0;                                                                         
(gdb) p string                                                                               
$1 = "1\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\061\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"             
(gdb) p string[0]                                                                            
$2 = 49 '1'                                                                                  
(gdb) p string[10]                                                                           
$3 = 49 '1'                                                                                  
(gdb)
```